# Replacing UNION ALL to increase speed when summarizing multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a dataset with columns `V1 V2 V3 V4 ... V200` where I would like to return a table with the column name and how many `NULL`, zero and below zero values each column has. My Current code looks like:

```
SELECT 'V1' AS column_name, SUM(CASE WHEN V1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS n_null, SUM(...V1 = 0) AS n_zero, SUM(... V1 < 0) AS n_below_zero UNION ALL
...
SELECT 'V200' AS column_name, SUM(CASE WHEN V200 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS n_null, SUM(...V200 = 0) AS n_zero, SUM(... V200 < 0) AS n_below_zero
```

Is there a faster way than this? I feel that 200 `UNION ALL` is not the fastest way

I am running on Databricks, so Spark SQL.

Comment: It is probably faster to have one full table scan and aggregate all rows to one row containing v1_null_cnt, v1_zero_cnt, v1_neg_cnt, v2_null_cnt, v2_zero_cnt, v2_neg_cnt, etc. Once you have this result row, you can unpivot it to get one row per table column.

Comment: I agree, but how can I perform one full table scan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be way faster to have one full table scan and aggregate all rows to one row containing all counts. Here is how to do that:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN V1   IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v1_null_cnt,
  SUM(CASE WHEN V1   = 0     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v1_zero_cnt,
  SUM(CASE WHEN V1   < 0     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v1_nega_cnt,
  SUM(CASE WHEN V2   IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v2_null_cnt,
  SUM(CASE WHEN V2   = 0     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v2_zero_cnt,
  SUM(CASE WHEN V2   < 0     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v2_nega_cnt,
  ...
  SUM(CASE WHEN V200 < 0     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v200_nega_cnt
FROM mytable;
```

Once you have this result row, you can unpivot it to get one row per table column, if you prefer this.

Comment: ~6x improvement, thanks.

Comment: I suggest that "it depends" -- probably on the size of the table, possibly on the complexity of the tests.

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN V2   < 0     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` can be shortened to `SUM(V2 < 0)`.  (This is because boolean expressions are 1 for True and 0 for False.)

Comment: @Rick James: I know this to be the case in MySQL. Is this the same in Databricks / Spark SQL?